# ColdFusion 2016 Developer Edition on Windows Case Sensitivity

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I just installed ColdFusion 2016 Developer Edition on my Windows 7 laptop and configured it to use the built-in web server. Previously I was using ColdFusion 11.

Now I have a case-sensitivity problem, but only for non-ColdFusion (.cfm) resources. For example, all css and js references are now case-sensitive, whereas they weren't when I was using ColdFusion 11. The same is true for calls to images and plain html files. All cfm files load just fine.

I modified the context.xml file (in the /cfusion/runtime/conf folder) to include `<Context AllowLinking="true" caseSensitive="true">` (and yes, I also tried caseSensitive="false") and have restarted several times, but no luck yet.

The 404 error messages specify Apache Tomcat/8.5.11.

Any ideas on how to restore case-insensitivity? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, the `caseSensitive=true` attribute was deprecated in Tomcat 7 and no longer works. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539116/tomcat-and-railo-need-to-be-case-insensitive-for-migration) for other options.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have "fixed" this. I enabled IIS on my laptop and used the Web Server Configuration tool to set it up with ColdFusion. (I also changed the path for the default website in IIS to /cfusion/wwwroot since that's where all my code is.) Everything seems to be working well now, with no case sensitivity for cfm or non-cfm pages. I no longer need to include the port (8500) in the URL for my applications, but do need to include it to reach the CF Administrator.